# Can't save ajax value to database

Tags: database, ajax, wpdb

So I'm making AJAX request and trying to save my quiz score to wordpress database. To start with, I don't even know which table would be the best for my case to save to or should I even consider making my own custom table for user scores?

Anyway, I get AJAX success message to console, and I can see my quiz score data in Dev Tools Network tab inside `admin-ajax.php` file headers. It returns 200 OK but for some reason, when I check my phpMyAdmin there is no data saved. I tried using global `$wpdb` aswell as `wp_update_posts`, `add/get/update_option`, etc. Here is some code:

script.js:

```
$.ajax({
      url: Questions_list.ajax_url,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        action: 'save_score',
        score: quiz.score
      },
      success: function (res) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(quiz.score);
      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log("error");
      }
    });
```

functions.php:

```
function save_quiz_score() {
     wp_send_json_error("Failed");

     $score = $_POST['score'];

     global $wpdb;
     $table_name = $wpdb -> prefix . "user_score";
     $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'name' => $_POST['score'] ) );
     return true;
     exit();


    /* add_option("user_score", $score);*/

     wp_send_json_success("score saved!");
 }

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_save_score', 'save_quiz_score');
add_action('wp_ajax_save_score', 'save_quiz_score');
```

I read other questions regarding my problem, tried following answers, but nothing works.

Comment: The first line of `save_quiz_score` ends execution and sends the message "Failed"?

Comment: @Milo Yes, it returns `{"success":false,"data":"Failed"}` even tho, the headers returns action:save_score
score:3 which is correct and what I need

Comment: `wp_send_json_error` halts execution, the rest of the code in that function will never execute.

Comment: @Milo Works like a charm, thanks! And regarding my first question, now I'm saving score to `wp_options` table, but what I'm working on is letting the user fill a form with his `name` and `email` and then take the quiz test. After he finish, put the `score` in database for scoreboard referencing later on. In that case, should I insert user `name` and `email` to `wp_users` table with those `name`, `email` keys and also add custom row for the `score`, or insert above data somewhere else, like `wp_options`? Or even create my own custom table? What is the best option here?

Comment: I'd keep it as user meta, there's a set of functions to add/update/delete user meta https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta

Actually you could let user's simply register as subscribers to use all the native goodies for users management. You can then easily query users by score meta field with https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

Comment: @LeviDulstein Thanks, I tried following your instructions, but it's not quite working. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/288438/register-new-user-and-add-custom-data-row-value-for-it